# FCM notification crash when app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, foreground

I am using FCM to send notification with data payload through app server, the notification is performing well while the app is in the background but crash when the app is in foreground see below

> 06-11 15:22:02.350 19744-19744/ng.proartisan.proartisans
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ng.proartisan.proartisans/ng.proartisan.proartisans.ServiceAddress}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                      at
>   ng.proartisan.proartisans.ServiceAddress.onCreate(ServiceAddress.java:77)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**This is my firebasemessagingservice.java :**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                sendPushNotification(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceAddress.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //  launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


    //this method will display the notification
    //We are passing the JSONObject that is received from
    //firebase cloud messaging
    private void sendPushNotification(JSONObject json) {
        //optionally we can display the json into log
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification JSON " + json.toString());
        try {
            //getting the json data
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            //parsing json data
            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            String phone = data.getString("phone");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");

            //creating MyNotificationManager object
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceAddress.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            //  launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(data.getString("title"));
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(data.getString("message"));
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(data.getString("phone"));
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
            notificationBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

            //if there is no image

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

while my ServiceAddress.java class (where the click action is directed to)is

```
public class ServiceAddress extends AppCompatActivity {
    String txtcategory, txttype, txtdetails,  txtcustomer,txtsection, txtphone, txtcustomer_name, txtrefnumber, txtaic;
    TextView category, type, details, customer, phone, customer_name,refnumber,aic;
    Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
    EditText txtDate, txtTime, txtAddress, txtLandmark, txtAdd_info;
    LinearLayout job_information, service_address;
    ImageView photo;

    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_address);

        category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
        type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type);
        details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details);
        customer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer);
        phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);

        job_information = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.job_information);
        service_address = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.service_address);
        customer_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
        photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        aic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aic);
        refnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.refnumber);


      /*  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        StringBuilder keys = new StringBuilder();
        String txtcategory;
        String txttype;
        String txtdetails;
        String txtcustomer = null;
        String txtphone;
        String txtcustomer_name;
        String txtphoto;
        String txtrefnumber;
        String txtaic;
        String txtsection;*/


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null)
       txtcustomer = extras.getString("acustomer");
        txtphone = extras.getString("phone");
        txtcategory = extras.getString("category");
        txttype = extras.getString("type");
        txtdetails = extras.getString("details");
        txtsection = extras.getString("section");

if(txtsection.equals("Notification")){
    job_information.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {

    service_address.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


        category.setText(txtcategory);
        type.setText(txttype);
        details.setText(txtdetails);
        customer.setText(txtcustomer);
        phone.setText(txtphone);
     customer_name.setText(txtcustomer_name);

    refnumber.setText(txtrefnumber);
   aic.setText(txtaic);


        final ImageView imgForward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.othersImg);

        btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.in_date);
        txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.in_time);
        txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        txtLandmark = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.landmark);
        txtAdd_info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_info);


        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ServiceAddress.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
        btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ServiceAddress.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                  int minute) {

                                txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void goforward(View v) {
String date, time, address, landmark, add_info;

        date = txtDate.getText().toString();
        time = txtTime.getText().toString();
        address = txtAddress.getText().toString();
        landmark = txtLandmark.getText().toString();
        add_info = txtLandmark.getText().toString();


        if ((date.equals("")) || (time.equals("")) || (address.equals("")) || (landmark.equals(""))) {
// Dialog Box to show error message for empty field
//
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ServiceAddress.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.second_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("ERROR");

            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            //set up text
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            text.setText(R.string.register_dialog_message);

            //set up button
            Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });
            //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it
            dialog.show();
        } else {


            ServiceAddress.GeocodingLocation locationAddress = new ServiceAddress.GeocodingLocation();
            locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                    getApplicationContext(), new ServiceAddress.GeocoderHandler());

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Subscription.class);
            //Create a bundle object
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            //Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle
            b.putString("date", date);
            b.putString("time", time);
            b.putString("address", address);
            b.putString("landmark", landmark);
            b.putString("add_info", add_info);
            b.putString("type",  txttype);
            b.putString("category",  txtcategory);
            b.putString("details",  txtdetails);
            b.putString("customer", txtcustomer);
            b.putString("phone", txtphone);

            //Add the bundle to the intent.
            intent.putExtras(b);
// Add values to SharedReference
            final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("CustomerAddress", txtAddress.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("CustomerLandmark", txtLandmark.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("CustomerAdd_info", txtAdd_info.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("CustomerDate", txtDate.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("CustomerTime", txtTime.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("RequestType", txttype);
            editor.putString("RequestCategory", txtcategory);
            editor.putString("RequestDetails", txtdetails);
            editor.putString("other_info", "");
            editor.apply();

            //start the Invoice Activity
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            String locationAddress, latitude, longitude;

            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                    locationAddress = bundle.getString("address");
                    latitude = bundle.getString("Latitude");
                    longitude = bundle.getString("Longitude");
                    break;
                default:
                    locationAddress = null;
                    latitude = null;
                    longitude = null;
            }
            //    latLongTV.setText(locationAddress);
            //   txtLatitude.setText(latitude);
            //     txtLongitude.setText(longitude);

            final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("Latitude", latitude);
            editor.putString("Longitude", longitude);
            editor.apply();

        }
    }

    class GeocodingLocation {


        private static final String TAG = "GeocodingLocation";

        public void getAddressFromLocation(final String locationAddress,
                                           final Context context, final Handler handler) {
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                    String result = null;
                    String strLatitude = null, strLongitude = null;
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
                        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                            Address address = addressList.get(0);
                            double latitude = address.getLatitude();
                            double longitude = address.getLongitude();
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
                            sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
                            result = sb.toString();
                            strLatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
                            strLongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Geocoder", e);
                    } finally {
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        message.setTarget(handler);
                        if (result != null) {
                            message.what = 1;
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                                    "\n\nLatitude and Longitude :\n" + result;
                            bundle.putString("address", result);
                            bundle.putString("Latitude", strLatitude);
                            bundle.putString("Longitude", strLongitude);
                            message.setData(bundle);
                        } else {
                            message.what = 1;
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                                    "\n Unable to get Latitude and Longitude for this address location.";
                            bundle.putString("address", result);
                            message.setData(bundle);
                        }
                        message.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }


}
```

I guess it has to do with passing message from onMessageReceived method to the ServiceAddress Activity

Comment: I guess it has to do with passing message from onMessageReceived method to the ServiceAddress Activity